# using Localized Carbon with diffForHumans duplicate number of days

Tags: php, laravel-5, php-carbon

in my page i show posts and i use diffForHumans  to display how mush  time pass when post  created and i translate it usin Localized Carbon in arabic language .
it's working but in days he display number of days two times .
for exemple instead of showing 5 days ago. he display  5 5 days ago

```
<div class="row" >
    <!-- properties -->
    @foreach($orderOffers as $key => $offer)
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
            <div class="properties">
                {{$var =\Carbon\Carbon::parse($offer->created_at)}}
                <div class="image-holder"><span><i class="fas fa-hourglass-start"></i>{{LocalizedCarbon::instance($var)->diffForHumans()}}</span>
                    <img src="{{asset($offer->firstimages)}}"  class="img-responsive dimensions" alt="properties">
                    <div class="status sold">
                        @if($offer->negotiable)
                            <i class="far fa-thumbs-up"></i>  قابل للتفاوض
                        @else
                            <i class="far fa-thumbs-down"></i> غير قابل للتفاوض
                        @endif
                    </div>
                </div>
                <h4><a href="property-detail.php">{{$offer->title}}</a></h4>
                <p class="price">{{$offer->price}}<i class="fas fa-hand-holding-usd"></i></p>
                <p class="price">{{$offer->city}} <i class="fas fa-map-marker"></i></p>
                <?php
                $id = $hashids->encodeHex($offer->id);
                ?>
                <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{route('offer.show',['id'=>$id,'slug'=>$offer->slug])}}">عرض المزيد</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

Comment: Does it work correctly when you switch the locale to English?

Comment: yes work correctly en English language

Comment: Are you using https://github.com/LaravelRUS/localized-carbon?

Comment: yes i use this extension

Comment: It's a bug in their code, you should create an issue.